# How do I plot output of function symclip?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am attemtping to recreate the m-file functions used by Zolzer in his Digital Audio Effects book. He has an M-file called symclip as shown below and I have included a recorded audio file to apply the clipping effect to. However, I cannot plot the output.

```
[x, fs] = audioread('E NOTE.wav');

% y=symclip(x)

% "Overdrive" simulation with symmetrical clipping

% x - input

N=length(x) ;

th=1/3; % threshold for symmetrical soft clipping

% by Schetzen Formula

for i = 1:N

if abs(x(i))< th, y(i)=2*x(i);end;

if abs(x(i))>=th,

if x(i)> 0, y(i)=(3-(2-x(i)*3) .^2)/3; end;

if x(i)< 0, y(i)=-(3-(2-abs(x(i))*3) .^2)/3; end;

end ;

if abs(x(i))>2*th,

if x(i)> 0, y(i)=1;end;

if x(i)< 0, y(i)=-1;end;

end ;

end;

plot(N, y)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: when trying to plot, MATLAB simply stops responding (as if it were processing something for ages) and I have to crtl+c to stop it.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on why you cannot plot the output? Did you get an error message, or was it something else? If it is an error message, please add that to the question as well, so others can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the script using the built-in `'handel'` audio in MATLAB. The only major concern in the script was the plot line. I think you'd want to plot the signal `y` against the sample index `N` which should be a vector that is the same length as the original and goes from `1` to `length(x)`. Also no need for semi-colons at following the `end` of if-statements.

[image: Audio Plotted]

```
%Loading built-in MATLAB audio%
x = load('handel').y;
fs = load('handel').Fs;

N = length(x);
y = zeros(N,1);
th = 1/3;

for i = 1:N
    if abs(x(i))< th, y(i)=2*x(i); end

    if abs(x(i))>=th
        if x(i) > 0, y(i)=(3-(2-x(i)*3) .^2)/3; end
        if x(i) < 0, y(i)=-(3-(2-abs(x(i))*3) .^2)/3; end
    end

    if abs(x(i))>2*th
        if x(i) > 0, y(i)=1; end
        if x(i) < 0, y(i)=-1; end
    end
end

N = (1:N);
plot(N,y);
```